# What does "multiple non-trivial solutions exists mean?"

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

I came across this question of solving system of linear non-homogeneous equations :

$$x+2y+z+4w=2$$
$$3x+6y+3z+12w=6$$

Options are :

1. Only the trivial solution $x=y=z=w=0$ exists
2. There is no solution
3. A unique non-solution exists
4. Multiple non-trivial solutions exists.

The answer is **Multiple non-trivial solutions exists.**

Can somebody explain me why and what does it mean? I always thought the rows in the matrix must be equal to the number of variables?

Comment: Multiply first equation by $3$, then it is equivalent to the second one

Comment: I observed that, but what does the "Multiple non-trivial solutions exists." part mean?

Comment: It just means there are multiple non-trivial (non zero) solutions. Any $(x,y,z,w)$ satisfying $x+2y+z+4w=2$ is a solution to the equation, and the solutions form a "hyperplane" in $\mathbb{R}^4$. For example both $(0,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,2,0)$ are non trivial solutions

Comment: A single solution is an ordered quadruple $(x,y,z,w)$. Multiple solutions means that there is more than one ordered quadruple which is a solution.

Comment: I suspect that option (3) is typed incorrectly, as it doesn't make sense as-is. Probably it should be "A unique non-trivial solution exists."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Multiple non-trivial solutions exist": a solution is called nontrivial if it is not identically zero (like in your option 1). So this statement means there are at least two different solutions to that equation which are not that particular zero solution.

*Edit* (actually the trivial solution does not satisfy the equation(s), so it is not a solution).

Comment: How do you solve this kind of system of equations?

Comment: @Sidsec9 This is what the branch of mathematics which is called '(linear) algebra' deals with. In this special case one of the comments contains an answer, the equation defines a hyperplane through through one special solution. More precisely, you try to find one solution to the so called inhomogenous equation (right hand side not zero, like in your example) and note that you can add any solution the homogenous equation (right hand side set to $=0$)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to consider systems of linear equations for which the number of equations is different from the number of unknowns.

For $m\times n$ *homogeneous* systems (right-hand side is $0$), there is at least the trivial solution. The set of solutions is a subspace of $\mathbf R^n$. If the system of equations has rank $r$, the space of solutions has codimension $r$, i.e. it has dimension $n-r$.

For $m\times n$ *non-homogeneous* systems, there is a  solution if and only if the rank of the augmented matrix is equal to the rank of the matrix of the homogeneous system. In such cases, the set of solutions is an affine space directed by the vector space of solutions of the homogeneous associated system.

Comment: But in this case, isn't the rank of the coefficient matrix 1 less than the augmented matrix?

Comment: If it is $1$ less, the set of solutions is empty: this means the right-hand side is not in the span of the columns of  the coefficients matrix.